# Extract entry keys from bib file and create a file for each entry key

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, python

In the context of ideas mentioned at [How to embed a review in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/488913/how-to-embed-a-review-in-biblatex) one should create a file for each entry key in the bib file. These files will be named to refer to each entry key, names will be like

```
bibannotation-entrykey1.tex 
bibannotation-entrykey2.tex 
bibannotation-entrykey3.tex
```

If bib file contains many entries might be interesting to automate it. How? I checked `biber --help` but doesn't seem to be something for this purpose there.

Comment: What do you want to automate? The creation of those files? Since the contents of those files have to be created manually anyway and `biblatex` automatically skips over non-existing files, I don't really see a point in creating the files automatically.

Comment: I was thinking in automate creation of files but after some more thinking I'm realizing this might not be a good thing, as you pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Biber certainly does not create these files for you automatically. Your best bet is probably a different programming language like Python or Perl with a library that can read `.bib` files (https://github.com/sciunto-org/python-bibtexparser, https://pypi.org/project/biblib/, https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::BibTeX, ...).

For example the following Perl script

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::BibTeX;

my ($bibfilename) = @ARGV;

unless (defined $bibfilename) {
  die "Please provide a file name";
}

if (-f $bibfilename) {
   print "Processing ${bibfilename}...\n";
} else { 
   die "File ${bibfilename} not found";
}

my $bibfile = Text::BibTeX::File->new($bibfilename);
my $entry;

while ($entry = Text::BibTeX::Entry->new($bibfile))
{
   next unless $entry->parse_ok;
   next unless $entry->metatype eq BTE_REGULAR;
   my $key  = $entry->key;
   my $file = "bibannotation-${key}.tex";
   unless (-e $file) {
     open TMPFILE, '>', $file and close TMPFILE
     or die "File error with $file: $!";
   }
}
```

when saved as `bibannotations.pl` and run as

```
perl bibannotations.pl <mybibfile.bib>
```

will produce empty files of the form `bibannotation-<entrykey>.tex` for all entries in the `.bib` file `<mybibfile.bib>`.

---

Technically, you don't even need a different programming language, you can have TeX sort this out. Just load all relevant `.bib` files in the following file and compile it with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}

\newwrite\filehandle
\AtDataInput{%
  \IfFileExists{bibannotation-\thefield{entrykey}.tex}
    {}
    {\immediate\openout\filehandle=bibannotation-\thefield{entrykey}.tex
     \immediate\closeout\filehandle}%
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

---

I believe, however, that there is little point in creating these files automatically. After all, you'll have to provide the contents of those files manually anyway. At least for the purposes of the `loadfiles` option discussed in [How to embed a review in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488913/35864) `biblatex` will just skip over non-existing files meaning that there is no point in having an empty file present.

Comment: Just curious about lualatex, which comes with some lua language, would this lua help?

Comment: @KcFnMi Yes, but as the second example shows you don't even need Lua. LaTeX is enough (as long as your entrykeys are well-behaved and don't contain any characters weird for TeX or for your file system: If you stick to ASCII only and avoid `/`, `\`, `.` and `:` you are probably fine.)