# Format "annotation" field in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I'm using biblatex to produce an annotated reading list. For longer annotations the formatting options available inside the annotation field are limited. Currently I'm using `\par` to get a new paragraph in the annotation in the reading list. Is it possible to get normal paragraphs working (`<CR><CR>`) inside the annotation? This would make external annotation files much more flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biber parses all new-line characters into normal spaces (as does BibTeX, I think), so you can't get a new paragraph with a blank line in the `.bib` file. `\par` seems the simplest option.

But I would say that the `.bib` file might simply not be the best place to write long annotations about your entries.

If you want to add larger annotations to your `.bib` entries it might be more convenient to use an external `.tex` file to store these annotations (where you can use blank lines for `\par`). See also [How to embed a review in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488913/35864), §3.13.8 *External Abstracts and Annotations* and §4.11.3 *External Abstracts and Annotations* of [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, loadfiles, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setunit{%
    \finentrypunct
    \renewcommand*{\finentry}{}%
    \par}%
  \usebibmacro{annotation}%
  \finentry
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author     = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title      = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date       = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibannotation-appleby.tex}
Lorem ipsum \[x^2+y^2=z^2\] that was mathy.
Also $a+b=c$ and so forth.
Just a few words to make the next
paragraph stand out properly.

We can even have a new paragraph.
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Entry with long annotation and new paragraph]

---

For a heavier paragraph markup you can either customise

```
\setlength{\bibparsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt}
```

or just change the paragraph settings before you print `annotation` (normally you would probably not set both `\parskip` and `\parindent` to non-zero values, but this is just for demonstration purposes)

```
\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \setunit{%
    \finentrypunct
    \renewcommand*{\finentry}{}%
    \par}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt}%
  \setlength{\parindent}{1em}%
  \usebibmacro{annotation}%
  \finentry
}
```

(I'm not too fond of having formatting settings like this just in a bibmacro, but that was the easiest way to get them right since they act on paragraphs.)

Comment: Thanks, external files is better. But, as far as I understand, this will still not produce proper paragraphs, i.e. indented first line or with a blank line.

Comment: @HansChr It does produce proper paragraphs, but the default setup (`\parindent`, `\parskip`) in a bibliography list is so that new paragraphs aren't that easy to spot. If you want all bib paragraphs to be more visible try something like `\setlength{\bibparsep}{0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt}`. Alternatively, you can modify `\parindent` and `\parskip` directly before you print the `annotation`.

Comment: @HansChr See the edit for what I meant.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @HansChr If the answer worked for you, you may want to consider upvoting and/or accepting it to mark the question as resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers